# Probability two matrices are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, finite-fields, random-matrices

Let $q$ be a prime integer. Let $\mathsf{Y} \in \mathbb{F}_q^{n \times n}$ be a particular full rank matrix.

Consider a matrix $\mathsf{X}$ sampled uniformly at random from the set of all matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q^{n \times n}$.

What is the probability that  $\mathsf{X} \mathsf{Y} = \mathsf{Y}$?

---

Unless $\mathsf{X}$ is the identity matrix, I suspect the probability is going to be negligible. But I could not formalize the intuition.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence, "Unless $\mathsf X$ is the identity matrix..."---the probability is a statement about the distribution of the random variable $\mathsf X$.

In any case, if $Y$ is full rank, i.e., invertible, can't we just right-multiply both sides by $\mathsf Y^{-1}$ to give $\mathsf X = \mathsf I_n$, hence $\Bbb P(\mathsf X \mathsf Y = \mathsf Y) = \Bbb P(\mathsf X = \mathsf I_n) = |\{\mathsf I_n\}| / |\Bbb F_q^{n \times n}| = q^{-n^2}$?

Comment: @Travis Willse: Excuse  me for the dumb question but, I see what you're saying until the $q^{-n^2}$. Where did that come from ? Thanks.

Comment: The set $\Bbb F_q^{n \times n}$ of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb F$ has $q^{n^2}$ elements, so the probability of picking a particular one from a uniform distribution is $1 / q^{n^2} = q^{-n^2}$.